# React: Reactstrap pagination active not working inside loop

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I want to set the item active when state == the index of loop. But I am getting false every time.

```
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            currentPage: this.props.currentPage
          };
         }
       render() {
            var lis = [];
            for (var i=1; i <= this.props.totalPages; i++) {
              lis.push(
                <PaginationItem
                  key={i}
                  active={
                    this.state.currentPage === {i} ? true : false
                  }
                >
                  <PaginationLink href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.handlePageClick.bind(this, i)} >
                    {i}
                  </PaginationLink>
                </PaginationItem>
              );
            }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting state based on props in `constructor` and it doesn't get updated if the props change, you need to update the state in `componentWillReceiveProps` function too. However you can simply use the props directly without setting it to state. Also use `let` instead of `var` for iterator declaration to avoid `closures`

```
   render() {
        var lis = [];
        for (let i=1; i <= this.props.totalPages; i++) { // use let here to avoid closure
          lis.push(
            <PaginationItem
              key={i}
              active={
                this.props.currentPage === i ? true : false
              }
            >
              <PaginationLink href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.handlePageClick.bind(this, i)} >
                {i}
              </PaginationLink>
            </PaginationItem>
          );
        }
        // more code here
     }
```

Comment: state is getting updated properly, also after updating the code given by you the issue is same, active=false for all the items

Comment: @Bhawna, can you check what value you get for this.props.currentPage in render

Comment: currentPage: 1, so I want 1 to be active, ref: http://prntscr.com/ixye3l

Comment: Updated the code , a small issue `this.props.currentPage === i ` and not   `this.props.currentPage === {i} `

Comment: Thanks. This was really small

Comment: @Bhawna Consider accepting and upvoting the answer if it helped